# Two Matrix plots side by side with image() function

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I'm using the `image()` function from the `Matrix` package and I want to plot two matrices side by side.

I have tried:

```
library(Matrix)
x <- Matrix(-9:15,nrow = 5)
y <- Matrix(-14:10,nrow = 5)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
image(x)
image(y)
```

but this does not work. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: `gridExtra::grid.arrange(image(x), image(y))`, as ?`image,Matrix-method` mentions it uses `latttice` which is based on `grid` graphics (hence why `mfrow` didn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` or `c()` from `latticeExtra` for the result you want:

```
library(Matrix)
x <- Matrix(-9:15,nrow = 5)
y <- Matrix(-14:10,nrow = 5)
imx <- image(x)
imy <- image(y)
# Using gridExtra package
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(imx, imy, ncol = 2)
# Using latticeExtra package
library(latticeExtra)
c(imx, imy, layout = c(1, 2), merge.legends = TRUE)
```

[Here](http://www.magesblog.com/2015/04/combining-several-lattice-charts-into.html) is a link with some examples with `latticeExtra` and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) is one with `grid.Extra` examples.